# A matrix satisfying a particular inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a matrix $A$ not diagonal, that satisfies the following inequality?

$$\exists \alpha>0 \;\;\;\ \forall \xi,\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\;\;\; \langle\eta,A \xi\rangle\geq\alpha\langle\eta,\xi\rangle$$

I think it's a generalization of the notion of ellipticity but I can't seem to find an example of which this inequality holds.

Comment: The answer below tells you that the notion above is not unfortunately a right way to generalize ellipticity : but as far as I know, there is a notion of *weak ellipticity*, which you can read up on [the wiki page for elliptic operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#General_definition). I believe every strongly elliptic operator should be weakly elliptic.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $y^T (A -\alpha I) x \ge 0$ for all $x,y$ then $y^T (A -\alpha I) x = 0$ for
all $x,y$ and hence $A = \alpha I$.